# Find the point on the curve where the plane perpendicular to the curve is parallel a plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

> Find the point on the curve $\langle t^3, 3t, t^4 \rangle$ where the plane perpendicular to the curve is parallel to the plane $24x + 6y – 64z = 0$

I assume to find this point I need to parameterize this equation with the curve?

$x \Rightarrow t^3=24u \Rightarrow u = \frac{24}{t^3}$

$y \Rightarrow 3t=6u \Rightarrow u = \frac{t}{2}$

$z \Rightarrow t^4=-64u \Rightarrow u = \frac{-t^4}{64}$

Am I on the right track here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to interpret each of the following steps for yourself.

$$\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
{x = {t^3}}\\
{y = 3t}\\
{z = {t^4}}
\end{array}} \right.{\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} \mathop  \to \limits^{{\rm{1st}}} {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
{\frac{{dx}}{{dt}} = 3{t^2}}\\
{\frac{{dy}}{{dt}} = 3}\\
{\frac{{dz}}{{dt}} = 4{t^3}}
\end{array}} \right.{\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} \mathop  \to \limits^{{\rm{2nd}}} {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
{3{t^2} = \alpha .24}\\
{3 = \alpha .6}\\
{2{t^3} = \alpha . - 64}
\end{array}} \right.{\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} \mathop  \to \limits^{{\rm{3rd}}} {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
{\alpha  = \frac{1}{2}}\\
{t =  - 2}
\end{array}} \right.{\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} \mathop  \to \limits^{{\rm{4th}}} {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
{x =  - 8}\\
{y =  - 6}\\
{z = 16}
\end{array}} \right.$$

Comment: I follow you up until the 3rd step.  What is the alpha?

Comment: @inquisitor: the tangent to the curve is parallel to normal vector of the plane! :)

Comment: @inquisitor: got it? :)

Comment: I think I'm starting to see it.  Sorry my class in online so I don't have a teacher providing chalkboard examples... it just makes it a little harder for me to learn this way.

Comment: @inquisitor: No Problem. :) Take your time to think! :)

Comment: OK here is what I can "see."  $\overrightarrow n = \langle 24,6,-64 \rangle$ and the tangent that is parallel to $\overrightarrow n$ is $\langle 3t^2, 3, 4t^3 \rangle$.  If I then set these equal to each other (as you did in the 3rd step) I have 3 equations with 2 unknowns.  These give me the values $2, -4$.  This is the part I don't understand.  What am I solving by setting them equal to each other?  The intersection of the normal vector with the point?

Comment: @inquisitor: Nope! when you say a vector is parallel to another vector, it means that it is a scalar multiple of the other, that is what the third step is telling you. $\alpha$ is that scalar! :)

Comment: @inquisitor: when you solve for $t$ and $\alpha$, it will tell you what is that scalar and also at which $t$ corresponding to a point on the curve, these two vector can be parallel. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31221/discussion-between-inquisitor-and-h-r).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
The tangent vector at $\bigl(x(t_0),y(t_0),z(t_0)\bigr)$ is normal to the plane $24x-6y+64z=0$.

So you have to solve for $\;\dfrac{3t_0^2}{24}=\dfrac{3}{6}=\dfrac{4t_0^3}{-64}$.

Comment: So I should be finding the derivative on the curve $\langle t^3, 3t, t^4 \rangle$ and using these as the $x,y,z$ values on the plane?

Comment: Not exactly: from the equation of the plane, you have a normal vector. The tangent vector must be colinear to this normal vector.

Comment: Ohhh... so instead I should be doing this: $24t^3+18t-64t^4$ and taking the derivative of this?

Comment: Sorry I'm having a hard time visualizing what's happening which makes the logic of what you're trying to say come slower

Comment: Two planes are parallel if (and only if) their normal vectors are colinear. I've added a detail. Is that clearer?